# Adjusting for an API that uses UTC (Twilio)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twilio

I'm using the Twilio API and am wondering how to adjust my request to compensate for the fact it uses UTC.  I have a heroku worker that runs every morning at 4am to collect all the calls placed to user accounts the day prior.  However, the calls it collects aren't the proper calls for what I deem as "yesterday" (I'm on PST) due to UTC.

For instance, if I make the following request (like their docs give as an example)

`@client.account.calls.list({:status => "completed", :start_time => "2014-06-01"})`

Instead of getting all the calls from June 1st in the response, I actually receive all calls from May 31st at 5pm until June 1st at 5pm - 7 hours from the day prior and 17 hours from day of.

My actual worker request is going to look something like this

```
date = date = (Date.yesterday).strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
@sub_account.account.calls.list({:status => "completed", :start_time => date})
```

Is it safe for me to manipulate that date object like so?:

```
date = (Date.yesterday - 7.hours).strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
```

Is that best practice for how I should generally deal with an API on UTC? Manipulate the date object on my side before making the request?

I'm still seeing inconsistencies between what they report in their interface and the API request but the disparity btwn the two is smaller.  As far as I can tell, their account interface has never matched up exactly with the API and the API is what matters to me.

Comment: I think the easiest way to avoid all the timezone confusions is to store date/times ONLY as UTC in your database. Then you can just format them to a timezone when you have to show it to an user, and use UTC everywhere else.

Comment: Hey, Twilio employee here. UTC is the standard for "computer time" and just like the previous comment, I'd suggest storing all datetime stamps in UTC and converting them programmatically to compensate for your time zone.

Comment: Since I'm doing daily downloads (clients need to see the stats next day) I should assume that I won't be able to gather a full days worth of stats until I get the following day as well.  Ex - want stats for June 2nd, won't be able to get them until the June 3rd scrape has run because a day in UTC time ends 7 hours ahead of me, correct?  I follow a similar daily worker model with a lot of other APIs and that isn't the case, including Plivo